# Extending PloneFormGen

Tags: python, forms, plone, ploneformgen

Are there any example add-ons where to look at when one would like to

1) Create custom action adapters for PloneFormGen

2) Add new field types to PloneFormGen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Plone collective has several examples:

- http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective//Products.PloneFormGen has a directory 'adapters' with two example and 'fields' with one example.
- Grepping through an 'svn ls' of the collective gives these results:

> ```
> collective.civicrm.civicrmpfgadaptor/
> collective.documentpfgadapter/
> collective.pfg.creditcardfields/
> collective.pfg.downloadfield/
> collective.pfg.masterselect/
> collective.pfg.silverpop/
> collective.pfg.sslfield/
> collective.pfg.verkkomaksut/
> pfg.donationform/
> pfg.drafts/
> raptus.multilanguagepfg/
> sc.pfg.brazilianfields/
> uwosh.pfg.d2c/
> ```

Of those, I have seen a lot of activity recently on collective.pfg.verkkomaksut.

Answer (score 3):

http://plone.org/products/salesforcepfgadapter has some examples, but probably on the more complex side.

Answer (score 2):

All PFG types, adapters etc. are all based on Archetypes. Related example code can be found in PloneFormGen/content. The saveDataAdapter.py or fields.py files provide reasonable example code...